# I cannot understand the following gnu assembly code for powerpc architecture

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, powerpc

```
#define START_GOT \
 .section ".got2","aw";\
.LCTOC1 = .+32768
```

Is **.LCTOC1** is a directive? Why is there a **.** before **+32768**?

Answer (score 3):

The `.` (dot) is a [special symbol](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html#Dot) that represents the location the current line is assembling into.

So, the expression `.+32768` means "32 KB from here", and that value is given the symbolic name `.LCTOC1`.

Note that the [`.section`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC119) directive which is also in the macro definition might change the value of `.`, i.e. the current location since it begins a new section called `.got2`. The `"aw"` argument means just "writable" (the `a` is ignored).

Comment: Am i right?
".LCTOC1" is defining a symbol
".LCTOC1 = .+32768" is "just" telling .LCTOC1 is equal to +32768

Comment: @ZhangBaolei: it is setting `.LCTOC1` to (current address) + 32768.